# Make background image 100% of viewport

Tags: css, background-image, viewport

I was looking for a solution to make my opening background image to be 100% of the viewport and after using Josh powel''s answer here [Page height to 100% of viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694130/page-height-to-100-of-viewport) it works on chrome on mac but not on any other browser (on mac or windows) When I say 'it works on chrome on mac', it works in most instances however if I stretch the browser too high, it doesn't fit to cover and I see my next bit of content so it's like it only works for heights up to x...

here's my code:

```
<section class="intro">
<div class="intro-body">
</div>
</section>




.intro {
display: table;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 350px 0 330px;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
position: relative;
background: url(http://www.wallsave.com/wallpapers/1920x1200/plain-blue-gradient/2567400/plain-blue-gradient-pc-mac-hd-2567400.jpg) no-repeat center;
background-size:cover;
}




.intro-page {
padding: 150px 0 130px;
background: url(http://www.wallsave.com/wallpapers/1920x1200/plain-blue-gradient/2567400/plain-blue-gradient-pc-mac-hd-2567400.jpg) no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
}

function windowH() {
var wH = $(window).height();

$('.intro, .intro-page').css({height: wH});
}
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/9h98f/1/

If anyone can shed any light, that'd be great.

Answer (score 3):

In order to make an element 100% height of the page, you must also have:

```
html,body { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; }
```

It's much better and more reliably to do this in CSS than by using JS.

Alternatively, you could just put the background image on the body (with `background-size: cover` like you are using).

Comment: Sorry, I actually already have that, i've updated my jsfiddle now http://jsfiddle.net/9h98f/3/

Comment: In reply to your other option, 'Alternatively, you could just put the background image on the body' I gave this a go and this works now on chrom and safari on mac but still not on IE, FF or CHROME (windows)

Comment: Plus works great on mobile, I wonder if it is my pc playing up with cookies/cache. I have deleted cache on all windows browsers

Comment: I was thinking you put the background on `.intro` for some restrictive reason that wasn't mention. If you can put it on the `body` then that is absolutely where it should go. Keep in mind `background-size` will not work in IE<9.

Comment: I put the background on .intro initially as it was parallax, I have 2 parallax backround images and this was one of them. Adding it to the body has lost the parallax effect but that's ok as still looks good. I'm using IE10 and still doesn't cover the screen or in the latest versions of FF or Chrome. basically on mac works fine, on pc doesn't