# How do I get document height using vh units in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport-units

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   $scrollingDiv.css("display", (($(window).scrollTop() / $(document).height()) > 0.1) ? "block" : "");
});
```

How can I change the unit `$(document).height()) > 0.1)` to 100vh? I don't have much jQuery experience.

Comment: Please check the parenthesis in your `$(document).height()) > 0.1)`

Comment: Is it `$(document).height()` or `0.1` that should be `100vh`? ... I also have difficult to understand what you want to do, so please make it clearer?

Comment: The `vh` is not a unit. The height of the viewport (vh) is also defined in pixel.  (If this is the question.)

Comment: `100vh` is basically the height of the viewport, i.e. `$(window).height()`

Answer (score 8):

**VH** : Viewport Height is similar to `$(window).height();` [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694130/page-height-to-100-of-viewport)

So you can check the condition `if (windowHeight > 0.1)` then

```
$("body").height(windowHeight);
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();

  if (windowHeight > 0.1) {
    alert("height is greater than 0.1");
    $("body").height(windowHeight);
  } else {
    alert("height is less than 0.1");
  }

});
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWzVwO

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct syntax is 
`$(selector).attr(attribute,value)`
So for your specific example `$(document).attr('height','100vh')`

Here is a link that hopefully helps --> https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp